Can't get "Colors.transparent" for bottom sheet to work when I set the background color of the main page to something else
I tried to make the bottom sheet look transparent when open it, and it did work at first. But then when I set the background color of the main page to something else, the bottom sheet no longer looks transparent when open it again.
Here's my implementation:
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(80, 75, 60, 10),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                expand: false,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                      top: Radius.circular(100.0)),
                ),
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CustomizedBottomSheet();
                }
              );
            },
            child: const Text(
              "open me",
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is what it looks like currently before I open the modal bottom sheet:

I wanna change my code so that when I open the modal bottom sheet:

It should have that kind of glass transparent effect.

can you add Screen shot of current and desired outputs for more clearity

@SakshiMahajan, done it

To Answer this question.
Here is the code
     showModalBottomSheet(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      isDismissible: false,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 32),
                          child: Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.5,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                       Text(
                                              "Some Text",
                                            ),
                                      GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.cancel_rounded,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                               
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );

this will work even if you change the color of your scaffold. remove or change the padding and radius as per your requirement.
